# Preventing CLIPS Rule from firing twice

Tags: clips

How could I prevent the following rule from firing twice, without retracting the initial facts?

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule cf_calculation
   (CF ?cf1)
   (CF ?cf2&~?cf1)
   =>
   (bind ?fCF (+ ?cf1 ?cf2))
   (printout t "the final CF is " ?fCF crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (CF 10))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (CF 5))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
the final CF is 15
the final CF is 15
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for inequality of the two values, check that the first is greater than the second:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule cf_calculation
   (CF ?cf1)
   (CF ?cf2&:(> ?cf1 ?cf2))
   =>
   (bind ?fCF (+ ?cf1 ?cf2))
   (printout t "the final CF is " ?fCF crlf))
CLIPS> (assert (CF 10))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (CF 5))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
the final CF is 15
CLIPS>
```